# I would like to replace last 2 digits in the mobile number with XX

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
str_builder_optin.Append( "<table id='mytable' width='300px'><thead><tr><th>Mobilenumber</th> <th>time</th><th>Date</th><th>Message</th><th>FirstTime</th> <th>Sent</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead><tbody>")
For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
      str_builder_optin.Append("<tr><td>" + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString() + " </td> <td>" + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(1).ToString() + "</td><td>" + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(2).ToString() + "</td><td>" + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(3).ToString() + "</td> <td>" + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(4).ToString() + "</td> <td>" + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(5) + "</td><td>" + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(6).ToString() + "</td></tr>")
Next
str_builder_optin.Append("</toby></table>")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO,  The Title and supplied code doesn't match, Please Provide necessary information to get better response from here. Add a description about the Problem, what you have tried so far, what is the issue that you are facing etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim mobile = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString()
Dim mobileWithXX = mobile.Substring(0, mobile.Length - 2) & "XX"
```

Comment: `ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0)` is `name` or some other value(may be). Why are you going for such a wide assumption? Hope that your reputation is enough for commenting

Comment: Looking at what he posted: `mobile` is in the first heading column. `ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString()` is in the first row column.